# IF function c++

Tags: c++

```
double x,y1,y2,y3;
cout << "Iveskite x reiksme: "; cin >> x;
if(x<=-5)
   y1=pow(x,2)+2;
   cout << y1;
if((x>-5) && (x<5))
   y2=2*x-5;
   cout << y2;
if(x>=5)
   y3=3*x+1;
   cout << y3;
```

This is the answer I get when I put `x` value as `-10`, however the answer is supposed to be `102`.

```
Iveskite x reiksme: -10
1022.05165e-3075.41618e+264
```

When I tried it with just one `IF` statement, it worked fine, but not with all of them.

Comment: You should use braces for your if conditions

Comment: Current indentation is misleading.

Comment: `c++ != python`. Indenting doesn't create scopes

Comment: Could you be more specific on the exact places I should place them?

Comment: Around what should be done when `if (condition)` is true

Comment: Put braces around any statements you want to be conditional on the `if` condition.

Comment: The next thing you should look up is how to debug your code. I would suggest a read of [this](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)  A few steps over your code would've shown you that the cout <<  y1 was being hit unexpectedly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use braces for your `if` conditions. Without braces, only the next statement is part of the `if` condition.

Your code is equivalent to this:

```cpp
double x,y1,y2,y3;
cout << "Iveskite x reiksme: "; cin >> x;
if(x<=-5) {
    y1=pow(x,2)+2;
}
cout << y1;
if((x>-5) && (x<5)) {
    y2=2*x-5;
}
cout << y2;
if(x>=5) {
    y3=3*x+1;
}
cout << y3;
```

but probably you mean this instead:

```cpp
double x,y1,y2,y3;
cout << "Iveskite x reiksme: "; cin >> x;
if(x<=-5) {
    y1=pow(x,2)+2;
    cout << y1;
}
if((x>-5) && (x<5)) {
    y2=2*x-5;
    cout << y2;
}
if(x>=5) {
    y3=3*x+1;
    cout << y3;
}
```